# The univalent domain of $\cos z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen in an exercie of Chapter 1 of "Concise Complex Analsysis" by Sheng Gong that the domain $$D=\{z\in C; a<\Re z<a+\pi\}$$ for any fixed $a\in R$ is an univalent domain of $\cos z$. But what I could only to do is that it is true for only $a=0$!

The method I do is as follows. Consider $w=\cos z$ as the composition of the following three maps:
$$\zeta=iz,\quad \xi=e^{i\zeta},\quad w=1/2(\xi+1/\xi).$$
Then $\zeta$ maps $D$ univalently onto 
$$D_1=\{\zeta\in C; a<\Im z<a+\pi\},$$
and $\xi$ then maps $D_1$ to be 
$$D_2=\{\xi\in C; a<\arg z<a+\pi\}.$$
But then $w$ is not univalently on $D_2$ for $a\neq 2k\pi,\ k\in Z$. For example, $a=\pi/2$, we have 
$$\xi_1=1/2,\xi_2=2\Rightarrow w(\xi_1)=w(\xi_2)!$$

Comment: A "univalent domain of $\cos z$" is a domain on which $\cos$ is injective? Then it's not true in that generality. $\cos$ cannot be injective on any domain containing a zero of $\cos' = -\sin$. One needs $a = k\pi$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true as stated. For example, $\cos z$ is not univalent in $\{z: -\pi/2<\operatorname{Re}z<\pi/2\}$ because $\cos (-\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$ (or, to give another reason, $(\cos z)'=-\sin z$ vanishes at $z=0$).

What is true is that for every integer $k$ the cosine  is  univalent in $$\{z:  \pi k<\operatorname{Re}z<\pi (k+1) \}\tag{1}$$ A direct way to see this is to use the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)
$$\cos z-\cos \zeta = 2\sin \left(\frac{z+\zeta}{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{z-\zeta}{2}\right)\tag{2}$$
which you can easily verify by converting everything into exponential form.

The sine function vanishes only at the integer multiples of $\pi$. For any two distinct elements $z,\zeta$ in the domain (1)  we have $$\pi k<\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z+\zeta}{2}\right)<\pi (k+1) $$
so the sine in (2) is nonzero. Also, $z-\zeta\ne 0$ and $$\left|\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z-\zeta}{2}\right)\right|<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
which together imply that the second sine in (2) is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation.